# join() for object properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am joining object properties by using a `for..in` loop. I wonder if there is an even easier way to this like `join()` for Arrays.

```
const data = { a: '213', b: 'asv', c: 'sdfs' }
let printData = ''
for (let attr in data) {
  printData += `${attr}: ${data[attr]}<br />`
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) could help you:

```js
const printData = Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}: ${data[key]}`).join("<br />");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try the combination of `Object.entries` and `Array.map`

```
const data = { a: '213', b: 'asv', c: 'sdfs' };
let printData = Object.entries(data).map(entry => entry.join(': ')).join('<br/>');
console.log(printData); // "a: 213<br/>b: asv<br/>c: sdfs"
```

Comment: Just a side note, [`Object.entries()` browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) is very low. Nice solution though!

Comment: Since the question is tagged with `node.js` I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: Yep, me neither, that's why it's only a *side note* ;)

Answer (score -2):

loop is necessary.
convert obj to array first, or override the Object.toString func